# How to open a VS2008 .csproj in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2008, csproj

I have been through all the answers for similar issues on StackOverflow, but not are the same problem. I bought a book and got zipped source code in VS2008. When I try to launch the .sln by double-clicking, I get an error

> '...' cannot be opened because its project type (.csproj) is not
>   supported by this version of the application. To open it, please use a
>   version that supports this type of project.

If I launch VS2013 Enterprise and select the directory where I unzipped the code, I see only a resources directory containing the sub project names (but they are empty to VS2013).
    [image: Error on double-clicking]
    [image: Opening VS and looking for the .csproj]
    [image: Within the resources folder]
    [image: Within a subdirectory]
    [image: After the error on double-clicking]
    [image: What types are available to open as]

I am out of my element here and the author is on the opposite side of the world asleep.

Comment: Something really basic to check:  When Visual Studio was installed, did you select C# as a language to load?

Comment: I did. It was the only language I would be using it for.